# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I really want to understand what is going on with my code.

I have a standalone application which uses spring and Hibernate as JPA and I am trying to run the test using a single main Class

My main class

```
package edu.acct.tsegay.common;

import edu.acct.tsegay.model.User;
import edu.acct.tsegay.business.IUserBusinessObject;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "Spring3AndHibernate-servlet.xml");
            IUserBusinessObject userBusinessObject = (IUserBusinessObject) context
                    .getBean("userBusiness");

            User user = (User) context.getBean("user1");
            user.setPassword("pass");
            user.setUsername("tsegay");
            System.out.println(user.getPassword());

            userBusinessObject.delete(user);

            User user2 = new User();
            user2.setUsername("habest");
            user2.setPassword("pass1");
            System.out.println(user2.getPassword());
            /*
             * userBusinessObject.save(user2);
             * 
             * User user3 = userBusinessObject.searchUserbyId("tsegay");
             * System.out.println("Search Result: " + user3.getUsername());
             */
            System.out.println("Success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

my application context is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <!-- session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />

        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">

            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>



    </bean>

    <!-- exposed person business object -->
    <bean id="userBusiness" class="edu.acct.tsegay.business.UserBusinessObject">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="user1" class="edu.acct.tsegay.model.User">
        <property name="username" value="tse" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Data Access Object -->
    <bean id="userDao" class="edu.acct.tsegay.dao.UserDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

My User Model is:

```
package edu.acct.tsegay.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Integer VERSION;

    @Version
    public Integer getVERSION() {
        return VERSION;
    }

    public void setVERSION(Integer vERSION) {
        VERSION = vERSION;
    }
    @NaturalId
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

My DAO is:

```
package edu.acct.tsegay.dao;

import edu.acct.tsegay.model.User;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UserDao implements IUserDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
        this.hibernateTemplate.save(user);
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.hibernateTemplate.delete(user);
    }

    public User searchUserbyId(String username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.hibernateTemplate.get(User.class, username);
    }

}
```

And this my stacktrace error when  i run the program:

```
pass
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: edu.acct.tsegay.model.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: edu.acct.tsegay.model.User
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:837)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:833)
    at edu.acct.tsegay.dao.UserDao.delete(UserDao.java:34)
    at edu.acct.tsegay.business.UserBusinessObject.delete(UserBusinessObject.java:30)
    at edu.acct.tsegay.common.App.main(App.java:23)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: edu.acct.tsegay.model.User
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1365)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:793)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:771)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$25.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:843)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: I don't see an annotation scanner in your spring config eg <context:spring-configured /><context:annotation-config />

Comment: Yes, I need to add the context namespace and add that config. Let me try it. Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to list your classes in your session factory configuration. You can have your entities auto-discovered if you are using `EntityManager`.

In order to use annotations with hibernate and spring, you have to use `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>edu.acct.tsegay.model.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    ....
 </bean>
```

Also, it is rather strange that your `User` entity is a spring bean. You don't need that. Hibernate entities are supposed to be created with the `new` operator.

Comment: I was thinking to do that, How do i list the classes in the session factory configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I got this error now org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: edu.acct.tsegay.model.User

Comment: I fixed the error above. I was using @NaturalId for the Identifier and I changed to @Id. now it is working fine.

Comment: And if you have configured the session facory in hibernate.cfg.xml, then add the mapping in here as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem and didn't find any good answer for this

What worked for me was to declare my entity class in the persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence ...>
    <persistence-unit ...>

        <class>com.company.maenad.core.model.News</class>
        <class>com.company.maenad.core.model.AdExtraInfo</class>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I struggled with "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity" for hours now, trying to understand why my definition of "packagesToScan" (under entityManager) didn't picked up my entities and now after adding it to my persistence.xml it works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bozho answer, if you are using spring + hibernate with annotation then in your session factory bean you can register your bean like below:

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(appContext.getBean(HikariDataSource.class));
localSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(
        AppUser.class, Assignment.class
);
```